# how to infer types based on exact function parameter value?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that streams some data

```js
function stream(variable:SomeEnum, callback:(message:Type) => void){}
```

How can typescript know to type of message based on variable?

I have cases where one stream may also return multiple types? Is it a better practice to have two different callbacks for such case?

```js
function stream(variable:SomeEnum, callback:(message:Type1|Type2) => void){}
```

Can generics or overloads solve this?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAyg9hYBRc0DeAoKUBuBDAGzGAEYAaLXQ4gJgu3yOAGYKBfDDAFwE8AHYFBSQAssADO4vAHNgIvHygBeKJmwBteImEQAdI2IkAugC4oAcjzmoAHwsAjcwG5KmhMlT7qwGqaip7YAAnFw0tD0gvJmY-ezg4AmA8EBc2FwwAMzAQAGMuAEs4EChxLiCkiAAeABUoYAAPLlAAE3FYdx0APgAKSnwg-Lx7RLNq+igcwgJ7PByAazNuxEkZYDMdMRXZeT51aqMASmVO3Dh85oojtA4MUvK8CG7wnSjDMigliSlZI6UT64OLiAA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: yeah I think this looks like a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for typescript [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). Basically, you will have a generic parameter that is constrained to extend `SomeEnum`.
Additionally, you will need some key-value type where the keys are the members of `SomeEnum` and values are the respective types of the message for the given member of `SomeEnum`:

```
enum SomeEnum {
  value1,
  value2,
  value3,
}

type EnumMessageMap = {
  [SomeEnum.value1]: 'a' | 'b';
  [SomeEnum.value2]: number;
  [SomeEnum.value3]: boolean;
};
```

Usage:

```
function stream<T extends SomeEnum>(
  variable: T,
  callback: (message: EnumMessageMap[T]) => void,
) {}

stream(SomeEnum.value1, (message:'a' | 'b') => {});
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAyg9hYBRc0DeAoKUBuBDAGzGAEYAaLXQ4gJgu3yOAGYKBfDDAFwE8AHYFBSQAssADO4vAHNgIvHygBeKJmwBteImEQAdI2IkAugC4oAcjzmoAHwsAjcwG5KmhMlT7qwGqaip7YAAnFw0tD0gvJmY-ezg4AmA8EBc2FwwAMzAQAGMuAEs4EChxLiCkiAAeABUoYAAPLlAAE3FYdx0APgAKSnwg-Lx7RLNq+igcwgJ7PByAazNuxEkZYDMdMRXZeT51aqMASmVO3Dh85oojtA4MUvK8CG7wnSjDMigliSlZI6UT64OLiAA)

Comment: what if variable `T` is an Object that holds a field `SomeEnum`? typeof keyof?

Comment: Then you can do like in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAyg9hYBRc0DeAoKUBuBDAGzGAEYAaLXQ4gJgu3yOAGYKBfDDAFwE8AHYFBSQAssADO4vAHNgIvHygBeKJmwBteImEQAdI2IkAugC4oAcjzmoAHwsAjcwG5KmhMlT7qwGqaip7YAAnFw0tD0gvJmY-ezg4AmA8EBc2FwwAMzAQAGMuAEs4EChxLiCkiAAeABUoYAAPLlAAE3FYdx0APgAKSnwg-Lx7RLM1bCg8Zub8gqLCM1KBkGlQ8dBIADVvM2rVtnooHMICezwcgGszbsRJGWAzHTFb2Xk+dWqjAEplTtw4fOaFG+aA4GEWFW6aDqqC2TDM4R0UUMZAmUxmhRA8ws1n2UGuEiksm+Sl+IM+LiAA)

Comment: oky, I see, it does not matter if the generic T is nested. thanks heaps!